# How do I extract with non greedy across multiple lines in java regular expressions?

Tags: java, regex, regex-greedy

If I have a bunch of data across multiple lines, how do I make it non greedy?  What I have is greedy.

example data

```
</TD> 
<TD CLASS='statusEven'><TABLE BORDER=0 WIDTH='100%' CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0><TR><TD             ALIGN=LEFT><TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0> 
<TR> 
<TD ALIGN=LEFT valign=center CLASS='statusEven'><A HREF='extinfo.cgi?    type=2&host=localhost&service=Current+Load'>Current Load</A></TD></TR> 
</TABLE> 
</TD> 
<TD ALIGN=RIGHT CLASS='statusEven'> 
<TABLE BORDER=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0> 
<TR> 
</TR> 
</TABLE> 
</TD> 
</TR></TABLE></TD> 
<TD CLASS='statusOK'>OK</TD> 
<TD CLASS='statusEven' nowrap>08-04-2011 22:07:00</TD> 
<TD CLASS='statusEven' nowrap>28d 13h 18m 11s</TD> 
<TD CLASS='statusEven'>1/1</TD> 
<TD CLASS='statusEven' valign='center'>OK &#45; load average&#58; 0&#46;01&#44; 0&#46;04&#44; 0&#46;05&nbsp;</TD>
```

Here's my code so far

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?s)<TD ALIGN=LEFT valign=center CLASS(.*)?<TABLE");
Matcher m = p.matcher(this.resultHTML);

if(m.find())
{
     return m.group(1);
}
```

Comment: If I may advice, DO NOT parse HTML with regex. It won't work next week. Use HTML parser, like Neko. Or HTMLUnit.

Comment: you might want to read the reply in this thread, its funny and true http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ungreedy:

```
Pattern.compile("(?s)<TD ALIGN=LEFT valign=center CLASS(.*?)?<TABLE");
```

Also, check this:

[Java Regexp: UNGREEDY flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552198/java-regexp-ungreedy-flag)

I've implemented `UNGREEDY` for JDK's regex.

Comment: I upvoted your answer, but I also want to re-state what you mentioned in your excellent comment to the original question: ***Don't parse HTML with regex***

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels what should I use then?

Comment: @deadfish use a dedicated html parsing library

Answer (score 2):

To make a quantifier non-greedy, you add a question mark immediately after it:

```
.*    // greedy

.*?   // non-greedy
```

What you've got there - `(.*)?` - is a greedy `.*` in a capturing group, said group being optional (the `?` is serving in its original role, as a *zero-or-one* quantifier).